# How to extract number after keyword with regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex

There is a string `I bought a beautiful gift for my friend. It cost me US$ 1,500.25. My friend was very happy. But then she asked for a US$1,700 gift`

I want to get the first double number `1,500.25` after the keyword `gift`.

How to do that with regular expression.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What did you already tried? And what was to result of what you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex -

```
gift.*?(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)
```

It works for the example in the question. Regex explanation can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/muoNrB/4)

Answer (score 1):

Regex part is:

```
gift.*?\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+?)
```

[Useful link](https://www.regextester.com/109425) to create regular expressions. 
[Tutorial](https://dl.icewarp.com/online_help/203030104.htm) for regex.

Comment: Please add a reference where you found this solution